# Handling PDO Connections in OO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I recently completed my first OO PHP project, and now starting my 2nd I want to get some closure on the nagging worries I had about my first approach.

My biggest concern is my database connection.

Here's what I did in my first project...

database.class.php

```
class Database
{
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';
    protected $db_name = 'mydbname';
    protected $db_user = 'mydbuser';
    protected $db_pass = 'mydbpass';

    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->db_host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

}
```

Then I had Dao classes for each of my database tables, that had their respective CRUD methods. Each of these classes extend my database class, meaning without any extra code, they have access to the PDO connection. For example;

```
class UserDao extends Database
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        /* Would be called automatically, but here for clarity */
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addUser($username, $password, $friendly_name)
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, friendly_name) VALUES (:username, :password, :friendly_name)");
        $encrypted = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $encrypted);
        $stmt->bindParam(':friendly_name', $friendly_name);

        $stmt->execute();

    }

    public function checkUserCredentials($username, $password)
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users where username = :username LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                return $row['id'];
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getUserById($id)
    {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT username, friendly_name FROM users WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $user;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

My worry is that I have read many answers on SO and Code Review, and there seems to be a lot of people who think wrapping PDO connection in a class is pointless.

However - I am sure these developers do not manually create a new PDO and pass the connection parameters every time they need to connect to the database  - therefore how do they achieve DRY principles without using a class?

One approach I assume would be a function in a config file that is included on each page...

```
function dbh_connect() {
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ward_stats', 'ward_stats_user', 'Mu9w!V5hhM');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Sorry, there was an error connecting to the database.<br>";
    die();
}
return $dbh;
```

}

Then, assuming I am passing this connection to a class that needs, using Dependency Injection, I could do the following in another script;

```
$dbh = dbh_connect();
$user = new UserDao($dbh);
```

Is one better than the other here? Or are there better ways to handle PDO connections in an objected oriented environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly, **dependency injection**. All the way. You only instantiate PDO once and pass it to every class that needs it.

Comment: Do you mean once per script?

Comment: Once per request/invocation. I guess that's the same as what you call "script".